# how to send array of struct with pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, file, struct

```
struct user{
char name[25];
int level;
double grade;
char password[10];}
```

and i want to write to a file with this function.
but it work for a one type of struct
i want save array of my top struct

```
void writeusertofile(user u){
fstream of("user.dat",ios::out|ios::app|ios::binary);
if(of.is_open()){
    of.write((char*)&u.level,sizeof(int));
    of.write((char*)&u.grade,sizeof(double));
    of.write((char*)&u.name,25*sizeof(char));
    of.write((char*)&u.password,10*sizeof(char));
}
```

Comment: a) Decide for *one* language. b) Read about proper serialization and the many pitfalls of it. int sizes, negative and floating point representation, alignment/padding, charsets ... At least until you understand that this is nonsense.

Comment: He does not have to decide anything, it's C++.

Comment: what does he want to do anyway.  
"i want save array of my top struct" is very confusing.

Comment: why .dat file not txt file.

Comment: @iharob After your tag edit, yes. Now it´s *bad* C++.

Comment: @Bot Nobody said something about txt, but yes, "dat" is not "txt". Why? Just because.

Comment: @deviantfan it's c++ because this syntax is invalid in c `ios::app` for instance. And `fstream` is a c++ class.

Comment: @iharob Yes, of course. My original sentence ("Decide for one language") was to tell OP that tagging C *and* C++ often makes no sense; that´s all. (Too many people are not aware of the difference)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you store your `user` structs in a `std::vector` and define another function like this (just one example of several alternatives):

```
void write_all_users_to_file(const std::vector<user>& v)
{
    //open file, check it's OK
    //write the number of user records you're saving, using v.size()
    for(auto& u : v)
    {
        //do your of.writes
    }
}
```

This will iterate over the whole vector of users and save each one of them. However, don't ignore the comment from deviantfan above - you can very easily get into trouble when saving data to a file the way you're doing it, especially since you'll want to read these things back.

Answer (score 0):

```
void writeusertofile(user u[],size_t s){
    fstream of("user.dat",ios::out|ios::app|ios::binary);
    for(int i=0;i<s;++i){
        of.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&u[i]),sizeof(user));
    }
}
int main(){
    user u[3]={
        {"theName",3,55.3,"pwd"},
        {"theName2",2,74.2,"pwd2"},
        {"theName3",7,24.6,"pwd3"}
    };
    writeusertofile(u,3);

    return 0;
}
```